# How to check if an id in one array of json objects exists in another nested array of json objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, lodash

I am making a call to two end points and need to display all the companies with their funds,name and factory that produces for that company.

here is the response from one end point

```
let factories = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Xintang",
        short: "xin",
        companies: [0, 4, 101,198]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Ohio Plant",
        short: "OHP",
        companies: [22, 27]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Cincy",
        short: "Cin",
        companies: []
    }
];
```

Here is the response from the second

```
let companies = [
    {
        id: 0,
        fund: "79588.96",
        name: "Microsoft"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        fund: "166727.06",
        name: "Comcast"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        fund: "131206.88",
        name: "Apple"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        fund: "74095.75",
        name: "HP"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        fund: "142556.86",
        name: "Dell"
    }
];
```

the dataset is much bigger, but here is just a sample. So I want be able to create a new object that links the factory with the specific company. Is there a way I can `map` over the companies and check which factory has the company `id` in that nested array so that I can add a new property `factory` to the company, and have a new array of objects that would look like this.

```
let returnedArr = [
    {
        id: 0,
        fund: "79588.96",
        name: "Microsoft",
        factory: "Xintang"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        fund: "142556.86",
        name: "Dell",
        factory: "Xintang"
    }
];
```

Comment: Why is `Microsoft` only added but not `Dell`? Both ids `0` and `4` exist in `companies`. Are you only wanting the first one found?

Comment: It was just an example of how I would want the final array of objects formatted, but yes, in this specific example I would want ```let returnedArr = [
 {
  id: 0,
  fund: "79588.96",
  name: "Microsoft",
  factory: "Xintang"
 },
 {
  id: 4,
  fund: "142556.86",
  name: "Dell",
  factory: "Xintang"
 }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Get the `company-id` and `factory-name` Map -> Then loop through the `companies` and create the output

```js
let factories = [{id:1,name:"Xintang",short:"xin",companies:[0,4,101,198]},{id:2,name:"Ohio Plant",short:"OHP",companies:[22,27]},{id:3,name:"Cincy",short:"Cin",companies:[]}],
    companies = [{id:0,fund:"79588.96",name:"Microsoft"},{id:1,fund:"166727.06",name:"Comcast"},{id:2,fund:"131206.88",name:"Apple"},{id:3,fund:"74095.75",name:"HP"},{id:4,fund:"142556.86",name:"Dell"}]

/*Get the company id: factory name mapping*/
const map = factories.reduce((m, f) => 
  (f.companies.forEach(c => m.set(c, f.name)), m)
, new Map);

const output = companies.map(c => ({...c, factory: map.get(c.id) || ''}));

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Yeah was looking for something like this, thank you sir!

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you good sir, will go back and update when i get some time!

Answer (score 1):

Try This.... It may help u...

```
    let result = [];
    companies.forEach(company => {
        let tempCompany = {...company};
        factories.forEach(factory => {
            let tempArray = factory.companies.filter(item => item === company.id);
            if(tempArray.length > 0) {
                tempCompany.factory = factory.name;
            }
        });

        result.push(tempCompany);
    });
```

Comment: tempCompany is new object, simply we are creating one more property for factory name and push it to new result array

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a map of company ids to factory ids, then just iterate through your companies array and add the corresponding factory to the company object, like so:

The big advantage of this is that your factoryid lookups will be `O(1)`, and it is `O(n)` to build the map. Your entire algorithm will be `O(n)`. This makes this extremely fast even for very large data sets.

```js
let factories = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Xintang",
        short: "xin",
        companies: [0, 4, 101,198]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Ohio Plant",
        short: "OHP",
        companies: [22, 27]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Cincy",
        short: "Cin",
        companies: []
    }
];

let companies = [
    {
        id: 0,
        fund: "79588.96",
        name: "Microsoft"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        fund: "166727.06",
        name: "Comcast"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        fund: "131206.88",
        name: "Apple"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        fund: "74095.75",
        name: "HP"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        fund: "142556.86",
        name: "Dell"
    }
];

var factoryMap = factories.reduce((res, curr) => {
  return Object.assign(res, curr.companies.reduce((_res, _curr) => (_res[_curr] = curr.name, res), {}))
}, {});

var mappedCompanies = companies.map(company => Object.assign(company, {factory: factoryMap[company.id] || ""}));

console.log(mappedCompanies);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a company can have more than one factory.

Try the following

```js
let factories = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Xintang",
        short: "xin",
        companies: [0, 4, 101, 198]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Ohio Plant",
        short: "OHP",
        companies: [22, 27]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Cincy",
        short: "Cin",
        companies: []
    }
];

let companies = [{
        id: 0,
        fund: "79588.96",
        name: "Microsoft"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        fund: "166727.06",
        name: "Comcast"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        fund: "131206.88",
        name: "Apple"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        fund: "74095.75",
        name: "HP"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        fund: "142556.86",
        name: "Dell"
    }
];

let returnedArr = companies.map(company => {
    company.factories = factories
        .filter(factory => factory.companies.includes(company.id))
        .map(factory => factory.name);

    return company;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(returnedArr, null, 4));
```